# use tag <script> with if in a Smarty template

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, smarty

i am using smarty template so i want use if with `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/bd/tazfy.js"></script>
```

i want to do somthing like that

```
{if $role neq 'vip'}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/bd/tazfy.js"></script>

{/literal}
{/if}
```

i try what they are saying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372380/use-tags-script-with-if-and-else) i don't know how to let that work for smarty template

can you help me please with that

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Smarty* but I would expect anything marked as *"literal"* to be taken literally... ***i.e.*** the `{$baseurl}` will be printed as-is rather than resolved.  According to [this documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal), it's only curly-braces that cause problems for the engine suggesting that you don't even need the `{literal}{/literal}` tags at all in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No need for literal just:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/bd/tazfy.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{if $role neq 'vip'}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/bd/tazfy.js"></script>

{/literal}
{/if}
```

this means:

```
if($role != 'vip')
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/bd/tazfy.js"></script>';
```

{literal} means in smarty that whatever the code is written in this will print as is not change in that it will basically used for javascript or css.